# applying css to everything inside element

Tags: html, css

How do I apply a css property to everything inside an element.

Like if I have:

```
p
    {
         font:15px "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
        padding-right:150px;
    }

<p>
<span>
<div>
</div>
</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You posted invalid HTML.  Block-level elements such as `<div>` do not go inside of `<p>` tags, and especially not inside of inline elements such as a `<span>`.

Anyway, the CSS selector to match anything is *****

```
p, p * {
    font: 15px 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-right: 150px;
}
```

Be careful using the * selector. It is "slow" when there are a lot of elements to match.

Comment: Been trying to use the universal selector and `p *` worked great!